# double star pointer pointing to a pointer of arrays; How do I access the pointer of arrays? C++

Tags: c++, pointers, char

I am coding in C++. While using pointers, I had a problem in accessing the the pointer of arrays.

```
char** p1;
p1 = new char* [MAX];
```

How would i access the array of pointers in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: each pointer shall be new'ed separately afterwards. p1[n] = new char [LEN];

Comment: @alfa then how would u access and/or change something in the new array of char assigned to p1[n]? would it be p1[n][c] something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simple:  `pi[i]` would access the element at index `i` in the array.  The valid indices, of course, are `0` .. `MAX - 1`.

Comment: There you go a +1 for a trivial question

Comment: @EdHeal :  :-)  It's a slow Friday night.

Comment: Early Saturday morning here and having a pint before the shops open, Xmas shopping etc.